# want to create repository in Github through Git API with Java

Tags: java, git

I want to create repository in github and after i want to push my code in to newly created repository. I can clone with help of Git

```
try {
        System.out.println("Cloning "+repoUrl+" into "+repoUrl);
        Git.cloneRepository()
                .setURI(repoUrl)
                .setDirectory(Paths.get(cloneDirectoryPath).toFile())
                .setCloneAllBranches( true )
                .call();
        System.out.println("Completed Cloning");
    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred while cloning repo");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But there is an API to Create repo in stash with help of curl

```
curl -u temp:tokenhere  https://github.com/api/v3/orgs/repos -d "{\"name\":\"$repoName\"}"
```

I want to do this in Java

Answer (score -1):

You can more detail on the available api from stash at below link:

Details here:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Git-questions/Programmatically-create-Stash-GIT-repos/qaq-p/204848

Example:

curl -u user:pass -X POST -H "Accept: application/json"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://stash/projects/QA/repos/" -d '{"name": "Repository Name"}'

Comment: you have to create a POST request with the needed arguments and body, I am not sure whats the problem here